# Default command handler in Eclipse E4

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I am migrating an existing plugin to the Eclipse E4 API.

We have defined some custom commands with default handlers, and I am trying to migrate these commands to E4, but I have not seen how to define a default handler for a command in E4.

Has this functionality been removed or where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Handler you define in the top level 'Handlers' list in the Application.e4xmi is effectively the default handler for the command.

Eclipse will choose the most specific handler for a command. So can also define Handlers for particular model element (such as parts or windows) and these will be use in preferences when that element is current.